# Value lost when transferring from server to client in silverlight

Tags: wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I am making a Silverlight app using WCF. I want to get the status of the hard-disks from remote servers and I am able to do that on the server side using a Management object. I have defined a wrapper class to hold the data of the hard-disks and store the objects in a list which I return.

Earlier, when the wrapper class was in the server project, it worked fine. However, when I transferred the class to a class library project in the same solution, the asynchronous call-completed event handler on the client side now gives me an event argument that is empty, i.e. an empty list

I tried debugging both the server and client code, and I see that the server creates the list properly and accesses the disk objects nicely. But the client code simply shows the list to be of size 0.

My client code is:

```
 private void getDiskStatus()
    {
        diskSpaceStatus.Text = "Running...";            

        if (server == string.Empty)
        {
            server = "localhost";
        }
        diskServer.Text = server;

        LogReaderClient proxy = new LogReaderClient();

        proxy.getDiskSpaceCompleted += new EventHandler<getDiskSpaceCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_getDiskSpaceCompleted);
        proxy.getDiskSpaceAsync(server);
    }



    void proxy_getDiskSpaceCompleted(object sender, getDiskSpaceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        diskSpaceStatus.Text = "Completed";

        try
        {
            List<uDisk> udisks = new List<uDisk>();

            foreach (Disk d in e.Result)
            {                    
                uDisk ud = new uDisk(d);
                udisks.Add(ud);
            }

            diskTable.ItemsSource = udisks;     


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Where uDisk is another wrapper class for the client side.

My server code is:

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<Disk> getDiskSpace(string server)
    {                        
        ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + server + "\\root\\cimv2", conn);
        try
        {                
            scope.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }         

        ObjectQuery oq = new ObjectQuery("select FreeSpace, Size, Name from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3");
        ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, oq);
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = search.Get();

        List<Disk> disks = new List<Disk>();

        Disk d;
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            d = new Disk(mo);                
            disks.Add(d);
        }


        return disks;   
    }
```

And the server wrapper class is:

```
namespace LogFilter.DataObjects
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Disk
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name;
        [DataMember]
        public double freeSpace;
        [DataMember]
        public double size;
        [DataMember]
        public double percentFree;

        public Disk()
        {}

        public Disk(ManagementObject mo)
        {
            this.name = Convert.ToString(mo["Name"]);
            this.freeSpace = Convert.ToDouble(mo["FreeSpace"]);
            this.size = Convert.ToDouble(mo["Size"]);
            this.percentFree = freeSpace * 100 / size;

        }
    }
}
```

The wrapper class is in the namespace LogFilter.DataObjects and the Server code is in the namespace LogFilter.Web.

Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Also can someone please give me a resource as to how to set the transfermode in a Silverlight application to Buffered?

Comment: Is the class Disk in exactly same namespace on client and server?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same namespace.